# How to retrieve one record at a time from SQL Server database in MVC Model

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working on Visual C# MVC project. I am using EF databse first approach in my model.My project is about developing an appmarket where users can buy apps. I used partial view in home page which will contain details of different apps in different partial views.Like App1 in 1st partial view, App2 in 2nd partial view, so on. For this I used for each loop.

In each partial view there is link called MoreInfo, so when user clicks on that they will go inside MoreInfo page. In database I have fields such as app info, app cost, description etc which will be displayed inside MoreInfo page. All these fields are in one table called Apps table.

When i follow Enumerable.FirstOrDefault approach I am able to retrieve only first record from database. But now my problem is I need to retrieve first record in my first MoreInfo view, second record in second MoreInfo view and so on.

My code for controller is :

```
public ActionResult MoreInfo()
{    
    var e = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(db.AppmarketApps);

    return View(e);
}
```

and in view i used :

```
@model Market.Models.AppmarketApp

<h3><span class="grey"><a href="#">MARKETPLACE</a> &#8250;</span> @Model.Description</h3>
```

So here I am getting first record description for all MoreInfo views which I don't want.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve one record from SQL Server database in MVC Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086712/how-to-retrieve-one-record-from-sql-server-database-in-mvc-model)

Comment: You should pass in the ID of the app and use that in your `MoreInfo` rather than always getting the first record.

Comment: Hang on @AndrewCounts - It is the same question by the same person?!

Comment: @AndrewCounts Its true that most of the contents are taken from my previous question.I tried to edit in that question only but I dint get any response so thought of making it as new question.

Comment: @Belogix its not same question brother. Its different question for same scenario from same person.

Comment: @Dev - Ah, I've added an answer to clarify my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment you should use the ID of the application and then pass that into `MoreInfo` so something like this:

```
public ActionResult MoreInfo(int id)
{    
    var e = db.AppmarketApps.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi I followed your steps but don't know what mistake I am doing.I am getting Parameter dictionary null error. What i did is, if i  have to display field OnCost which is of type int i typed          public ActionResult MoreInfo(int id)
{    
    var e = db.AppmarketApps.Where(x => x.OnCost == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(e);
}                                                                    and then in moreinfo view i typed  @Model.OnCost. but its not working.Do i need to use foreach loop ??

Comment: No, where you have `db.AppmarketApps.Where(x => x.ID == id)` that is "Selecting" the record so you need to have an ID or similar that you can look up in your database. Then, on your View you would have `@Model.OnCost` or similar to get the value.

Comment: i am using db.AppmarketApps.where(--) in MoreInfoController. can you tell what small id and CAPS ID here?? Sorry it may be dumb question but i am stucked here

Comment: Sure, the small `id` is the parameter that is being passed into the action `MoreInfo` so will contain the record we are looking for, i.e. Record 23. Then inside the `Where` is what is called a **Lambda** so `x => x.ID` means you `AppmarketApp` class will be seen as `x` so if you have a property called `ID` it will work. If you have a property called `AppID` for exmple you would change it to `x => x.AppID` etc. So, if you had a Record 23 you could write just `x => x.AppID == 23`. But you want the number passed in as parameter so you get `x => x.AppID == id`. Hope that makes it clearer?

Comment: To help me further can you post the properties of your AppmarketApp that you are getting back (i.e. OnCost) etc?

Comment: thanks for explanation.I understood how it works and I did changes as you mentioned and I am passing OnCost ID right now in ActionResult and in view I am using @model.OnCost, but i am getting error.properties I have on AppmarketApp are AppOrder, Name, Description, OnCost,MpnthCost, Instructions, Reviews.

Comment: @Dev - Curious as to why you didn't accept my answer as you used it verbatim in your solution below? I also explained Lambdas that you also used below in your explanation (i.e. x.ID == id)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35060/discussion-between-dev-and-belogix)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the Id of the app of interest in the link to MoreInfo and query your data based on that id.

Comment: Hi can you just explain by taking my code as example. Please.

Comment: I think you should look up a basic Asp.Net MVC tutorial that shows you how to pass information to the controller from your view.  The net is full of such tutorials. Start by looking at the official Asp.Net MVC site itself

Answer (score 0):

Finally after playing with my code I got to know solution for this.

Before I had two controllers called HomeController and MoreInfoController. But since MoreInfo link was in Homepage itself, I removed MoreInfo controller and added code to HomeControoler itself. Here is the code which i add :

```
public ActionResult MoreInfo(short id)
    {
        var e = db.AppmarketApps.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(e);
    }
```

Here I am passing id as parameter and capital 'ID' is my primary key.Since i wanted to display only one record per view, i used FirstOrDefault method.

After this in my view I changed code like this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("MoreInfo", "MoreInfo", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "greyButton" })
```

Here first parameter "MoreInfo" is LinkName and Second parameter "MoreInfo" is link. As you can see when user clicks on MoreInfo link, id will be passed to that link by using

```
new { id = item.ID }.
```

class is used for style purpose. 
To be clear what above code does is, it will pass id to MoreInfo link and will display data present in AppmarketApps table.

Finally  i used @Model.Name in my view if i wanted to display 'Name' and I used @Model.Description if i wanted to display 'Description' and so on.

Thanks to all who helped me in this.